# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{(-1)^n-2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{(-1)^n-2} $ converge?

I tried this way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{(-1)^n-2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^3} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+1)^3}$$

The first one is harmonic series and therefore diverges, 
the second one diverges by comparison test with harmonic series, 
and the third and forth converge by comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}$.

May I conclude that the original series diverges as sum of convergent and divergent series ?

Comment: It is not clear what your series is? Are you saying that the exponent in the denominator is $3$ for odd numbered terms and $1$ for even numbered terms? If so, then Sami Ben's answer is correct. But this doesn match with what you wrote when describing your try....

Comment: You cannot draw conclusions from having split up a series like that, unless everything is absolutely convergent.  A conditionally convergent series can do very weird things when you start rearranging, and everything goes out the door with divergence.

Comment: My series is $\sum_1^\infty n^{(-1)^n-2}$ I edited the question and title

Comment: If I cannot draw conclusions from my try, what should I do to solve this question ?

Comment: @user97484 See Sami's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: your series is greater than
$$\sum_n \frac {1}{2n}$$
so conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
The difference of the harmonics $\large\tt converges$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over n +2}}}
=
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 2}}
=
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 3}}
=
\Psi\pars{3} - \Psi\pars{1}
\\[3mm]&= \Psi\pars{2} + {1 \over 2}  - \Psi\pars{1}
=
\Psi\pars{1} + {1 \over 1} + {1 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{1}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large {3 \over 2}}
\end{align}
$\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\tt\mbox{digamma function}$.

Comment: There's no need of that to prove above sum is 3/2. Note that $\sum\frac{1}{n}-\sum\frac{1}{n+2}=1+1/2$. All the other terms cancel out.

Comment: @Grobber That is *very* sloppy and likely to get you in to trouble when you try to apply it in other cases.